# Showing week date range along with week summary in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working to prepare a report for my project where i am showing previous 4 week summary based on single column. Here is my query.

```
`SELECT `TBL33_ORGID`,
/* Trend DAK calcualation */
SUM(IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '12', `TBL33_DAK`, 0)) AS week_1st_dak,
SUM(IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '13', `TBL33_DAK`, 0)) AS week_2nd_dak,
SUM(IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '14', `TBL33_DAK`, 0)) AS week_3rd_dak,
SUM(IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '15', `TBL33_DAK`, 0)) AS week_4th_dak,
FROM `tbl33_snapshotorg`
WHERE   YEAR(`tbl33_date`) = '2015'
AND  (WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '12' OR WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '13' OR WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '14'  OR WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '15' )
GROUP BY `TBL33_ORGID``
```

My this query output is quite fine but now i need to  show week start date and end date.
    I have been tried in following way but not worked perfectly.

```
`IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '12',MIN(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_1st_start, 
IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '12',MAX(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_1st_end,

IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '13',MIN(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_2nd_start, 
IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '13',MAX(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_2nd_end,

IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '14',MIN(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_3rd_start, 
IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '14',MAX(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_3rd_end,

IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '15',MIN(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_4th_start, 
IF(WEEK(`tbl33_date`) = '15',MAX(`tbl33_date`),null) AS week_4th_end `
```

How can i achieve that without doing any extra query.

Comment: and you run it in sql server and mysql?

Comment: Sorry! Its entered mistakenly

Comment: You say it didn't work perfectly - what was the expected and/or ideal result and what result did it output?

Comment: You seem to have your integer values inside single quotes. That's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You wan the conditional expression *inside* the aggregation function -- "conditional aggregation":

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN tbl33_date = 12 THEN tbl33_date END) as week_1st_start,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tbl33_date = 12 THEN tbl33_date END) as week_1st_end,
       . . .
```